# Optimizations causing weird bug, putting a variable in a state it should not be in

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I have code that renders to the screen the frames/second of the business logic thread, and if it is configured as a client, it displays the frames/second of the server as well.
I'm displaying some info on a top line, and then below it the FPS data, next to each other.
When running in Debug, everything is aligned properly, but once switching to Release, the Server FPS line displays at the correct x coordinate, but the y coordinate of the top line, overlapping it.

```
enum class UseCase
{
    Server,
    Client
};

struct Point
{
    float X = 0;
    float Y = 0;
};

void RenderText(const char* str, Point pos){...};

void UIWindow::RenderFPS()
{
    float x0 = TopLeft().X;
    float y0 = TopLeft().Y;

    Point textPos;
    textPos.X = x0 + 2;
    textPos.Y = y0;

    const int bufferSize = 512;
    char buffer[bufferSize];

    RenderText("Top line info", textPos);
    // Omitted code here that writes some stuff to the buffer,
    // bug happens even if these lines are commented
    textPos.X += 100;
    RenderText(buffer, textPos);
    
    textPos.X = x0 + 2;
    textPos.Y = y0 + 16;
    RenderText("Local FPS:", textPos);
    textPos.X += 65;
    _snprintf_s(buffer, bufferSize, "%.1f", 1000.0 / FrameTime);
    RenderText(buffer, textPos);

    if (Designation == UseCase::Client)
    {
        //textPos.Y = y0 + 16;    // Weird magic going on here
        textPos.X += 60;
        RenderText("Server FPS:", textPos);
        textPos.X += 75;
        _snprintf_s(buffer, bufferSize, "%.1f", 1000.0 / ServerFrameTime);
        RenderText(buffer, textPos);
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the commented line, everything works again, even in Release, but I have no idea why, since it is just a copy of the line setting the same variable to the exact same value, with no changes to it in between. Commenting out the `if` statement also has it working, but is not a solution, although it may offer some insight as to what is going on. I can't do any debugging on `textPos` since in Debug there is no issue, and in Release the variable is optimized away. Anyone have an idea what is going on here?

*Notes:*

`Designation` is an `extern` of type `UseCase` that is set pretty much as the first thing in `WinMain()`, by reading a config file. It is never changed past that. `FrameTime` and `ServerFrameTime` are `extern double`s, the first of which is set by the thread it is timing, and the latter is received through the communications thread. They both count the time it takes for 1000 iterations of the relevant loop.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019, Version 16.11.3.

Comment: @NateEldredge as I mentioned, it is optimized away, no address to watch. `Point` is just a struct of 2 `float`s, and `RenderText` copies by value and does not change the original. I don't see where any undefined behavior can sneak in

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Bug still happens even if I comment out the frame timers and just use a constant `double` in their place. `Designation` is set once at the beginning of the program and is never changed

Comment: Code changing behavior with/without optimisation is often a symptom of undefined behaviour (e.g. falling off the end of an array, dereferencing a NULL, using a dangling pointer) - and that may be in the obviously affected code or in *some other* code. Optimisation changes the program's memory layout, so changes what is tromped by the bad operation, so changes the symptom. As strange as it sounds, you need to *also* look at other code in your program. Also  `char buffer[bufferSize];`, where `bufferSize` is a variable, is not valid C++ (it is a VLA, which some compilers support as an extension)

Comment: It looks like both "Local FPS:" and "Server FPS:" are set to be rendered at Y position `(y0 + 16)`, is that intentional?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, they are on the same line, at different x positions

Comment: @Peter `bufferSize` is a `const int`, and the bug still happens if it is `constexpr int`. I have a lot of code in my program, I can't just go over all of it hoping to catch something, especially since the rest all seems to work fine

Comment: Is there a reason you're using X and Y coordinates as a float type to do integer math?

Comment: @EyalK.  Yes, `bufferSize` is a `const int` - since it is a variable, your code is not valid C++. In any event, as I said, the problem is some other part of your code. Larger code bases are more likely to have unintended interactions between unrelated sections of code -and your description is consistent with that. There may also be multiple causes.  Your only options are trial and error (e.g. eliminate some code and have problem go away) or audit of code or design. If you can't/won't do that then you doom your project to a persistent bug that nobody is inclined to expend the effort to find.

Comment: @CarloBanfi floats are used in the rest of the graphics code, just this particular section doesn't need the extra accuracy.